# nodemailer custom host without authentication

Tags: node.js, typescript, smtp, nodemailer

I have a custom smtp host that doesn't require any authentication (internal use only, need to be on a VPN) and I'm unable to get it working with NodeMailer.

Currently I'm doing

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "customHost.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
  });


let info = transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'from-email@example.com',
    to: 'foo@example.com',
    subject: 'Hello!',
    html: 'This is a test',
});

console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
```

Which results in

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.48.1.36:587
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
  errno: -60,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.48.1.36',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

I was able to get this working with [smtp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smtp-client), however that library doesn't seem to support sending HTML, which I need.

Has anyone been able to get authless hosts work with NodeMailer?

Comment: Your error doesn't look auth related...

Comment: It looks to me like it's unable to Connect to the host I'm using, however as I mentioned I can use the same host with `smtp-client` and it works fine.

Comment: Can you show the code when you use `smtp-client`? Maybe there's a vital difference that wasn't translated to nodemailer?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this after a bit more chasing.

I believe by default `nodemailer` uses port 587 (and of course I had it defined as well, but even removing that line doesn't work), and so I had to override it to use Port 25 by default. Additionally I had to set it up to accept self-signed certificates. My transporter now looks like

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "customHost.com",
    port: 25,
    secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });
```